# Is there a way to create multiple 'WHERE' clause on a query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Let's say I have this table and its row

[image]

And I am expecting to get only each of the `post_id` and `student_id`

For `post_id` = **1** neeed to get only these

```
> 1. Capital of Australia
> 
> 2. Capital of Philippines
> 
> 3. What is the color of pineapple
> 
> 4. What is the color of mars
```

For `post_id` = **7** neeed to get only these

> ```
> 1. What is the law of war?
> 2. What is the color of tree?
> ```

And this is my query - I need to select the student id to show each student their data and post id for each of the students data.

```
public function results($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('results');
    $this->db->where('student_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('post_id', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('question');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: `$this->db->where(['student_id' => $id, 'post_id' => $id]);`

Comment: how can student_id and post_id same?

Comment: type here the query that full fills your expectation? If not add table schema here with some sample data.

Comment: by first view i feel the column student_answer saves real answer and vice versa. You should normalize the question table to another one with real answer and use the id here as it is replicating here many time.

Comment: You seem to be asking the following query: "please show me all the questions for a given student_id and a given post_id". This is a query which logically depends on 2 parameters. Your function `results` only has one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an associative array having all the `conditional parameters` to your
`$this->db->where($array);` clause as per `Codeigniter` user guide. [check this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->db->group_start()->where($first_condition)->group_end();
$this->db->group_start()->where($second_condition)->group_end();
$this->db->get()
```

You can modify each condition between `group_start()` and `group_end()`.
Hope it works to you.